# in flutter ,Custom View refresh is affected by a Text which refreshes second by second

Tags: flutter

[image: here is the gif]

I custom a progressbar extends CustomPaint.then I put it in one Page,it runs fine.Next，I put a Text in the same Page,which shows the current time and refreshes second by second.Here comes the issue,The progressbar is refreshing not correct,it refeshes second by second too,not smoothly.I dont know why.

Here is my code:

```
class TimeWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return TimeState();
  }

}

class TimeState extends State{
  var bloc;
  static const eventChanel =
  const EventChannel('com.example.flutterapp/main_event');
  StreamSubscription _timerSubscription;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bloc = BlocProvider.ofTime(context);
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: bloc.stream,
        initialData: bloc.value,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(
          "${snapshot.data}",
        ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _enableTimer();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _disableTimer();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _enableTimer() {
    if (_timerSubscription == null) {
      _timerSubscription =
          eventChanel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen(_updateTimer); // 添加监听
    }
  }

  void _disableTimer() {
    if (_timerSubscription != null) {
      _timerSubscription.cancel();
      _timerSubscription = null;
    }
  }

  void _updateTimer(time) {
    if (bloc != null) {
      bloc.setTime(time);
    }
  }
}
```

progressbar:

```
class ProgressbarWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ProgressState();
  }

}

class ProgressState extends State{
  double _progress = 0;
  StreamSubscription subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    var stream =
    new Stream.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));

    subscription = stream.listen((result) {
      if (_progress < 360) {
        _progress += 10;
      } else {
        _progress = 0;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: CustomPaint(
        painter: ProgressBar(_progress),
    ));
  }
}


class ProgressBar extends CustomPainter {

  ProgressBar(double progress){
    this._progress = progress;
    //print(progress);
  }
  Paint _btmPaint = new Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black12
    ..isAntiAlias = true
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 20;

  Paint _progressPaint = new Paint()
    ..color = Colors.lightGreen
    ..isAntiAlias = true
    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 20;
  double _progress;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, 0), 50, _btmPaint);
    Rect rect = Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(0, 0), radius: 50);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, _progress * 3.14 / 180, false, _progressPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a gif of the problem?

Comment: sorry,I forgot .I have added the gif@miguelpruivo